# Automatic rewrite when slug changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-rewriting

I've got a site with profiles where the slug can be changed by the user. I would like to implement automatic rewriting of these slug changes. Either in Ruby or Nginx, is there any libraries or guides on how to do this?

There's these https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/URL_Rewriting but at what layer would this best be implemented?

What's your experiences and best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a library around. But would I would do is:

- Save the former slugs of a user, p.e. using [paper trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)
- When finding the user by slug considering the former versions as well
- Redirect on application level to the most recent slug (user.slug)

If you follow that approach it assumes that a slug already used by a user in the past cannot be reused.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah I guess that would work, would there be a performance difference in doing it this way versus say, writing nginx/apache rewrites?

Comment: It would be slightly slower as you have to use the application. How big the impact is depends on how slim you can write that part (skipping stuff like authentication). Also I suggest using the status code of 301 (moved permanently) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes